# What is the difference between linting and debugging?

Tags: debugging, difference, lint

Is it just that linting is a type/subset of debugging? Like, linting will analyze static code syntax but debugging uses a variety of techniques to fix code in a variety of ways? Or is it more complicated than that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linting can prevent debugging by catching bugs before you manually run your program. It will run the code and check for errors. Debugging is something you manually do after a bug is found.

Comment: I don't think linting will actually 'run' the code.  Some static analysis tools will  effectively run the code (via interpretation or some other sandbox), but lint, in the original sense is really just a really picky compiler with all the warnings turned on and a few extra checks.